# Is there a way to avoid too many __init__.py in a highly module python library?

Tags: python

I'm creating a Python project with several image processing blocks, with multi-level folders as under:

```
folder1
  __init__.py
  somecode1.py

  folder11
    __init__.py
    somecode11.py

    folder111
      __init__.py
      somecode111.py

  folder12
    __init__.py
    somecode12.py

  .......

folder2
  __init__.py
  somecode2.py
  ....
```

What this enables me is to enable these modules very easily, for example as under:

```
from folder1.somecode1 import XYZ1
from folder1.folder11.somecode11 import XYZ11
from folder1.folder11.folder111.somecode111 import XYZ111
```

Having so many **init**.py leaves my project with too many files.
Is it possible to have:
(1) Such a folder structure for my code
(2) Ability to import modules as above

And do the above without have so many **__init__.py** at each level?

Why I want this?
- To reduce the cognitive load of seeing so many files in my git repository.

Comment: What makes the number of files "too many"? Modern computers can handle billions of files with no problem.

Comment: It's just too many files I see my git repo. Without so many __init__.py, would make the git repo look much cleaner to me. Yes, modern computers wouldn't have a problem at all handling billions of files.

Comment: What is the actual problem that the "too many" files are causing? `git` won't have any problem with them either.

Comment: Do you actually *need* all those levels of nesting? Do you think that they add anything to the usability of your library? Namespaces were conceived to avoid name conflicts, not to invent infinitely deep arbitrary taxonomies with just a couple of identifiers in the leaf nodes of the hierarchy.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://punchlet.wordpress.com/2011/06/18/letter-the-sixth-belatedly/; it's about C++, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Any directory with an `__init__.py` file is considered a Python package. The different modules in the package are imported in a similar manner as plain modules, but with a special behavior for the `__init__.py` file, which is used to gather all package-wide definitions.

A `a.py` in the directory `root/` is imported with the statement `import root.a`. This statement will look for an `__init__.py` file in root, execute all of its top-level statements. Following that, it will look for a file named root/a.py and execute all of its top-level statements. After these operations, any variable, function, or class defined in a.py is available in the root.a namespace.

There is a convenient syntax is available for importing deeply nested packages: `import very.deep.module` as example. This allows you to use example in place of the verbose repetition of `very.deep.module`.

Comment: Not quite sure how this answers the question?